# Content assist without choosing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Is there a way, like some key binding or some settings, to make the content assist to choose the best match one, or the first one, without showing the window? It's always faster when only one choice is available, like
many other IDE has done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [blogpost](http://www.langrsoft.com/blog/2009/06/eclipse-auto-insert.html)

Short summary: 
Rename the content assist tag that is triggered to something unique (blog author changed "test" to "tst") and change the template to have auto-insert enabled. 
When your template is the only choice, it will then be autoinserted.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. It's a pity though that template names must not be prefixes of each other to avoid non-auto-insert. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. It would require multiple keybindings ala [Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), and Eclipse has only notion of "content assist" which is used for autocompletion of everything that could be useful when you invoke it.

Besides, "best match" sounds to me like it would be very annoying, since IDE's best guess might not be your best guess.

Comment: In fact, I'm looking for textmate-like snippets in eclipse, and found the code templates. But the template system in eclipse is built in content assist, and one of its features is that when two templates has similar names(one is a prefix for the other), the content assist showed up.
It's really uncomfortable and low-efficient for just expanding a template with choosing.