# Automatically insert first choice in Eclipse content assist

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

One thing I like about Visual Studio is that you can automatically insert the first choice of the content assist instead of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and then choose the first option from the menu.

Is there a similar way to map a special key combination to always insert the first choice in Eclipse ?

If such option is not a native option in Eclipse, is there a plugin for that ?

I have seen a similar question in SO : [Content assist without choosing in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477805/content-assist-without-choosing-in-eclipse) but the solution suggested there was to rename the content assist tag that is triggered to something unique, I'm looking for something that works for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Nope auto-insert only works when there is only one choice.

You may open an enhancement request for this feature against JDT/Text - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JDT